# How should I send additional authorization id?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I've got a case where in every request that goes to api there's property like

```
public Guid CompanyId {get; set;}
```

It is then checked with UserId from JWT token to check if user has access to that particular company.

I don't want that property to be in every call to the api. Is there a better way to approach that, like creating custom claim in JWT token?

It gets a bit more complicated cause users can have access to more that one company, so if I were to go with the custom claim, is there any way to refresh the token and change claim value in it?

Comment: You can certainly add that to the JWT, just look online how to do it. If a user can access multiple companies, it might make sense to put all company ids in the JWT and then check the company selected against the JWT (faster than database, of course). Otherwise, creating a new JWT might make sense but you'd essentially log the user out and in, depending on your flow (if consumed from mobile app, web app, MVC, etc)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a similar function to issue Tokens for your users and pass in current session company Id and add it to them claims

```
public string IssueToken(Guid userId, Guid companyId)
{
  
  SigningCredentials siginingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SuperSecretKey")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

  JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: "Issuer",
    audience: "Audience",
    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
    signingCredentials: siginingCredentials,
    claims: new List<Claim>
            {

                new Claim("companyId",companyId.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,userId.ToString())
            }
   );

   return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

and then later on you can access them by using HttpContextAccessor

```
Guid? UserId = Guid.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
Guid? CompanyId = Guid.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("companyId"));
```